# RxJS delay on observable of string

Tags: typescript, rxjs, pipe, delay

How can I add a delay on an Observalbe?

Here is my code (this code is on a pipe):

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'toTitle',
    pure: false
})
export class ToTitlePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }

    transform(model: BaseModel | ModelType): Observable<string> {
        return this.getModelTitle(model).pipe(map(title => {
            if (model instanceof BaseModel) {
                const classSettings = model.modelType.getClassSettings();
                if (classSettings && classSettings.toTitle) {
                    return `${title} ${model.modelType.getClassSettings().toTitle(model)}`;
                }
                return `${title} ${model.primaryKey}`
            }
            return title;
        }), delay(0));
    }

    getModelTitle(model: BaseModel | ModelType): Observable<string> {
        return of('test');
    }
}
```

It works well when I remove the delay, the title is correcty returned. But when I add this `delay(0)`, the transform method returns null.

I have to use a delay because of an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

Why does the `delay` pipe returns null?

**EDIT:**

Here is how I consume the pipe:

```
{{model | toTitle | async}}
```

When I try this : `(model | toTitle | async) === null`, it returns `true` on the template.

Comment: Are you sure the method itself returns null? Could you please show how do you consume this pipe in the template?

Comment: @OphirBushinsky I've updated my code.

Comment: try replace delay with timer(0)

Comment: @FanCheung timer is not appropriate in this case because it returns a Observable of number. See https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html

Comment: It would be easy to help you if we would have some reproducible example (stackblitz)

Comment: @Ben use timer at the beginning and switchMap to request